# Angular 1.5.8 [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

this is a typical error I know, but none of what i've tried worked out, must be something really silly:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");
}]);
```

I've this scripts linked in my html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: I struggled with this for two freaking days, and after posting here, it took me 20 seconds to review my html for the 20nd time and finde the mistake:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
```

to

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: show your code for HTML

Comment: ok then close the question